# J2ME:Downloading an Image from server and saving on Mobile

Tags: java-me

I'm trying to download an image from server and save the image on mobile phone.I'm able to download the image but I need to resize the image and then store the image to mobile.

the code is like this.

```
public void requestPlatform(String strURL) throws IOException {
try {

    System.out.println("requestPlatform");

      byte [] imageBytes = null;

    if ((im = getImage1(strURL)) != null) {
        im=resizeImage(im, width, height);
           if(im!=null)
        {
            System.out.println("Image");
        }

        else
            System.out.println("NoImage");
        imageBytes=get_Byte_Array(im);

        fileCon=(FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///root1/photos/diwali1.jpg",Connector.READ_WRITE);

        fileCon.create();
        if(fileCon.exists())
        {

            System.out.println("File created");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("File not created");
        }

        out = fileCon.openDataOutputStream();


          if(imageBytes!=null)
        {
            out.write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        }
        if(out!=null)
        {
            out.close();
        }
        if(fileCon!=null)
        {
            fileCon.close();
        }
        im2=Image.createImage(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);

        canvas.repaint();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Msg: " + e.toString());
}
}

public byte[] get_Byte_Array(Image img) {

    int[] imgRgbData = new int[img.getWidth() * img.getHeight()];
    byte[] imageData2 = null;
    try
    {
    img.getRGB( imgRgbData, 0, img.getWidth(), 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight() );
    } catch( Exception e )
    {
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( baos );

    try{
    for( int i = 0; i < imgRgbData.length; i++ )
    {
    dos.writeInt( imgRgbData[i] );
    }

    imageData2 = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();
    dos.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    return imageData2;
    }
```

The problem is when I'm trying to resize the image and then save it on phone it just creates a file but there is no image.So i think there is some mistake while i'm converting image to byteArray.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to transform image is preparing it on server side. But if you aren't able to do this create image from byte data and after that use method

```
Image.createImage(Image image, int x, int y, int width, int height, int **transform**)
```

It's very expensive in resources (memory and cpu utilization) but the easiest way.

About saving. You can save data into RMS (this is possible on all J2ME mobiles) or to file system (only on devices with JSR-75 FileConnection API).

Comment: you can't use this method to resize an image, resize images is not supported natively in JME.

Comment: So you need to implement your own resize algorythm. See http://developers.sun.com/mobility/reference/techart/design_guidelines/image_resizing.html or http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?73221-How-to-resize-image-using-MIDP-2.0

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to resize your image, although it is better to resize it on the server instead of doing this on the phone. you need to adapt it to resize the image to a specified width and height.

```
private Image resizeImage(Image src) {
      int srcWidth = src.getWidth();
      int srcHeight = src.getHeight();
      Image tmp = Image.createImage(screenWidth, srcHeight);
      Graphics g = tmp.getGraphics();
      int ratio = (srcWidth << 16) / screenWidth;
      int pos = ratio/2;

      //Horizontal Resize        

      for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++) {
          g.setClip(x, 0, 1, srcHeight);
          g.drawImage(src, x - (pos >> 16), 0, Graphics.LEFT | Graphics.TOP);
          pos += ratio;
      }

      Image resizedImage = Image.createImage(screenWidth, screenHeight);
      g = resizedImage.getGraphics();
      ratio = (srcHeight << 16) / screenHeight;
      pos = ratio/2;        

      //Vertical resize

      for (int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++) {
          g.setClip(0, y, screenWidth, 1);
          g.drawImage(tmp, 0, y - (pos >> 16), Graphics.LEFT | Graphics.TOP);
          pos += ratio;
      }
      return resizedImage;

  }//resize image
```

this code is taken from [here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/reference/techart/design_guidelines/image_resizing.html)

Comment: hey thanx a lot it was really helpful.But i'm getting one problem when i'm saving my image using FileConnection the file is getting created but there is no image to display.If anyone has any idea plz do reply as soon as possible

Comment: it is hard to tell where the problem is without seeing your code. It should work without problems. Is the image created? can you open it with any native application on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

This is a great Image resizing script that I use. Hope it serves your needs.

```
public Image ResizeImage(Image image, int resizedWidth, int resizedHeight) {  
    int[] in = null, out = null;  

    int width = image.getWidth(), height = image.getHeight();  
    in = new int[width];   

    int i=0;  
    int dy,dx;   
    out = new int[resizedWidth * resizedHeight];   

    for (int y = 0; y < resizedHeight; y++)   
    {   
        dy = y * height / resizedHeight;  

        image.getRGB(in,0,width,0,dy,width,1);   


        for (int x = 0; x < resizedWidth; x++)   
        {   
        dx = x * width / resizedWidth;   

        out[(resizedWidth * y) + x] = in[dx];  
        }   
    }   
    Image resized = Image.createRGBImage(out,resizedWidth,resizedHeight,true);  
    return resized;   
}
```